# Codeigniter Session Expires on Clicking on Google Geo Map

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am using Google Geo Map for State and City wise. When we click on the Map, we are genrating a Jquery Data Table pop which works dynamic. We are using Ajax and Json output for Jquery Data Table to work as Dynamic. Now the issues is, when we click on the Map, the pop up loads, when close the pop up and refresh, the CI Session is getting destroyed and the user is getting logged out. Kindly help us in fixing this. Thanks

Comment: In your config file, have you checked to make sure all the session configuration is OK?

Comment: Yes, we did, many times, but no fix. When we check in firebug it is clearly showing that the ci_sessions are getting expired.

Comment: Is this a Firefox bug? Does it have the same problem in IE, or Chrome?

Comment: Yes, In all three browsers.

Comment: I have a Question, does CSS conflicts can cause a CI Session destroy!! I am Sorry asking a Strange qn.

Comment: CSS conflicts will have nothing to do with the CodeIgniter sessions.

Comment: 100% Correct, But, I am actually testing right now, If remove the customized CSS that I have written for the Jquery Data Table, the Session is NOT getting expired. But, this cannot be the solution, right.

Comment: Can you post some code? Maybe the CSS/Js that is conflicting with the session?

Comment: Exactly the same I wanted to know, I am guessing the same. We are using fnDestroy() in Jquery Data Table to clear the JSON output data. Does this function can cause a CI Session destroy ??

Comment: Well, the codes are heavy, cannot post in a forum.